# Watching JIRA changes

Tags: tracking, jira

I am interested in a particular Apache JIRA and would like to know when someone comments on the JIRA or changes the state of the JIRA. So I browsed to that particular JIRA and enabled "WATCH" on it.

Now, how do I get notified for any changes to the Apache JIRA?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-279

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get notified at that the email you used when you created your account on apache's jira instance when anything changes to that project, depending on the notification scheme the jira administrators have configured.  I'd guess new comments would get a notification.